# Storing big JSON response in a variable using SwiftyJson is very slow

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I am using Alamofire and SwiftyJson to handle JSON is swift. After receiving a response which is huge, I am storing the response data like this:

```
let xData = data["data"].arrayValue
```

But, I did some timing on this line and it is taking about 4 seconds to just store the data in the variable.

Is there any way to make it faster?

Comment: Just how big is the data? is `data` a dictionary, if so it is badly named.

Comment: `SwiftyJSON` is open-source code and you can debug it. Just use `NSLog` that prints out timestamp

Comment: Data is an array. @MaximShoustin - Thanks for the idea. I will check.

Comment: @Zaph - How would I get how big the data is? I mean how much memory it takes?

Comment: Why did I get a negative here? What is wrong in asking this?